# Regex match a preceding exact text or nothing

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to execute a regex which will search in a domains list and check if the provided domain is a white list or not

let's say my main domain www.testDomain.com

I need a regex to match all subdomains and with different extentions, i've tried that and it works well, here's the regex:

```
"([a-z0-9]*.)([a-z0-9]*.)testDomain.(com|cn|local)"
```

But i have a case in which, i have the following domain

```
xxx.test-testDomain.com
```

i need to match the exact `test-` text or nothing,because i might have a domina `xxx.anyString-testDomain.com`, which is not allowed to pass
, i've tried the following one

```
([a-z0-9]*.)((?!.test-|(?!)))testDomain.(com|cn|local)
```

but doesn't work, any suggestion to do it?

Cases:

```
http://abc.impersonate-testdomain.com -- shouldn't pass
http://testdomain.com -- ok
http://abc.testdomain.com -- ok
https://abc.testdomain.com -- ok
https://abc.test-testdomain.com -- ok
http://abc.testdomain.local:8081 -- ok
```

Comment: `\\w+\\.test-\\w*.*` would do, yet a few more examples would be good to get a more convenient result. Should `xxx.test-test1Domain.com` pass? Or what about `xxx.test-noTestDomain.com`?

Comment: First you need to escape the `.` or it will match any char in a regex.

Comment: I've added a set of test cases, the first one shouldn't pass

Comment: @Thefourthbird not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below regex:

```
([a-z0-9]*\\.)?(test-)?testdomain.(com|cn|local)
```

[image]

Comment: As shown in the screenshot, first one does not match completely

Comment: Or if you want to ensure that only complete url match or does not match at all, you can add start end identifiers:  ^([a-z0-9]*\.)?(test-)?testdomain.(com|cn|local)$

Comment: Yes after es capping the dot

Comment: this works ([a-z0-9]*\.)?(test-)?testdomain.(com|cn|local)

Comment: @M1M6 Yes, that was some issue with stack overflow textbox. I had to add two slashes (\\.) to add one (\.). :) But yeah, the one provided in the screenshot works fine